# Vulkan reading a storage buffer returns zero

Tags: buffer, vulkan, compute-shader

In my compute shader I have a very simple piece of code

```
layout(set = 0, binding = 3) buffer Velocity{
    vec3 velocities[];
};

void main(){
    uint gID = gl_GlobalInvocationID.x;
    velocities[gID]=vec3(1,2,3);
    vec3 velocity = velocities[gID];
    debugPrintfEXT("%d (%v3f)", gID, velocity);
}
```

but the logs that I get are rather unexpected

```
0 (1.000000, 2.000000, 3.000000)
1 (0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000)
```

When I allocate the buffer, I specify it's size as

```
buffer_create_info.size = sizeof(glm::vec3)*capacity; //here capacity==2
```

so I'm sure there should be enough space in that buffer.
I also double checked if the binding number is correct.
This buffer is used by only this one shader and there
are no other threads/shaders that could lead to data races.
I have validation layers enabled and I see no problems there either.

What could be the cause of such strange behavior? Has anybody seen such problems before?

Edit:

I tried allocating buffer larger than necessary and it seems to help. I still don't understand why. The `sizeof(glm::vec3)` returns `12`. When I set `capacity==3` that gives me buffer of `36` bytes. It should also work with `24` bytes, but for some reason reading from such a buffer returns zeros.